# Magento connect manager renders blank page

Tags: magento, ubuntu, connect

I just installed Magento 1.4.1.1 on my Ubuntu Apache server and everything is working just fine aside from one thing:
The Magento Connect Manager simply brings up a blank page. In Firebug it is just `<html><body></body></html>`.  I read that it might be permissions but I gave 777 permissions to the Magento directory and all subdirectories and still the blank page.
Any ideas?

Comment: Ensure php errors are being displayed, and use your step by step debugger.

Comment: I have the same problem on a fresh install.  The only odd thing i did is magento is not in the webroot, its in a folder in the webroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for some reason it was looking for a PEAR file in a non-existant location.  Magento included this in line 27 of PEAR.php:

```
$_pearDir = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . DS . 'downloader' . DS . 'pearlib';
```

However, this led it to a directory that included "/includes", which wasn't correct.  I ended up just putting

```
$_pearDir = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . DS . '../downloader' . DS . 'pearlib';
```

Notice the only difference is the "../" in front of downloader to remove the "/includes" directory from the path.  But my real question would be why Magento would have this error in the first place.  This couldn't have happened to everyone who installed Magento on an Ubuntu server, right?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today without changing anything (no updates etc.) ... blank page when trying to access Magento Connect from backend.

With the help of the answer above I was able to get it to work again. So in Magento base directory go to /includes/src/Varien/ and make the change in Pear.php (include ../ before download) in line 12.

It still would be nice to know what really caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my solution is 100% related to your issue - but I had been struggling with a blank page for Magento Connect Manager too (version 1.4.0.1)

After a couple hours I discovered that the `pear.ini` file (*/downloader/pearlib/pear.ini*) needed to be updated.

It may happen that the filepath references in your pear.ini are not up to date in the case that you changed servers, installations or Magento directory locations.

Therefore you need to do two things:

1. Open your `pear.ini` in a text editor and update all filepath references with your current Magento directory location.
2. Adjust the number of characters for each string. A bit of a pain, I know but it works. (you can use a word editor to do your character counts)

For example:

```
s:59:"/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/Test/downloader/pearlib";
```

where "s:59" is the number of characters in the path `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/Test/downloader/pearlib` and "Test" is the old directory.

Upon going live (i.e removing "Test" folder) This needed to be updated to:

```
s:54:`/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/downloader/pearlib`;
```

Let me know if you have luck?